# Highlight Collapsible DIV's on Search Keyword

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been working on creating an HTML page for my company that will contain a list of contacts for an "experts list". Currently the list is based of collapsible DIV's and are nested within one another.

The HTML page also contains a search feature that will allow a user to search through the list. Here is the current HTML outline I have...

`<div>
    <input type="text" class="live-search-box" placeholder="Search Here" />
    </div>

<div >
    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
        <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true" data-theme="a" data-content-theme="a">
            <h3>Category</h3>
            <p>Defenition</p>
            <div data-role="collapsible" data-theme="a" data-content-theme="a">
                <h3>Sub-category</h3>
                <div data-role="collapsible" data-theme="a" data-content-theme="a">
                    <h3>Location</h3>
                    <p>Point of Contact</p>
                </div><!-- /section 1A -->
            </div><!-- /section 1 -->
        </div>

        <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true" data-theme="a" data-content-theme="a">
            <h3>Category2</h3>
            <p>Defenition2</p>
            <div data-role="collapsible" data-theme="a" data-content-theme="a">
                <h3>Sub-Category</h3>
                <div data-role="collapsible" data-theme="a" data-content-theme="a">
                    <h3>Location</h3>
                    <p>Point of Contact2</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


    </div>
</div>`

The thing is, I'm trying to implement a Highlight Feature that will highlight the keywords in the live-search-box. That way it will be easier for a user to find the keyword within the HTML page.

Here is the working jfiddle I'm trying to implement the Highlight feature: https://jsfiddle.net/dgaz8n5k/21/

I already tried using the jQuery highlighter from [here](http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/highlight-javascript-text-higlighting-jquery-plugin.html) but it breaks my search feature which isn't good.

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: I think it working fine, just a little changed. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dgaz8n5k/23/). By the way, in `'[data-search-term *= "' + searchTerm + '"]'` line, you should use "" to make sure `searchTerm` is one param not separate by _ (empty space).

Comment: @HaizhouLiu this works great! I would accept this as the answer if you post it :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please check this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dgaz8n5k/23/).

For each `keyup` event, update the highlight word.

```
// remove prevoius highlight
$(this).removeHighlight();
// add new highlight
$(this).find('h3').highlight(searchTerm);
$(this).find('p').highlight(searchTerm);
```

The `filter` method should use "" to warp `searchTerm` to make sure it is one param and not separated by _ (empty space).

```
'[data-search-term *= "' + searchTerm + '"]'
//                    ^                  ^
```

Also need add `.highlight { background-color: yellow }` to css file.